# Geoserver Layers from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, geoserver, wms

I am new to javascript and I believe that syntax is the error.
I have a problem with geoserver and Leaflet.

```
mylyr = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mydata/wms?', {layers: 'mydata:parcels'});
```

This works perfectly. But I need to get layers of a variable.

```
var mygeodata = "'mydata:" + "parcels'"
```

When I put this in my code, does not work:

```
mylyr = L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/mydata/wms?', {layers: mygeodata});
```

What can I do to work?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably not include quotes within your string:

```js
var mygeodata = "mydata:" + "parcels" // Result: mygeodata = "mydata:parcels"
```

…instead of:

```js
var mygeodata = "'mydata:" + "parcels'" // Result: mygeodata = "'mydata:parcels'"
```

Comment: You are welcome, thank you for the feedback! Please note that the SO way to thank people is also to _accept_ the answer that helped you solve your issue. Once you get enough _reputation_, you will also have the ability to _upvote_. Cheers!